# How to fix Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@~4.5.1

Tags: ios, build, ionic2, platform

I am developing a hybrid app using Ionic 2 and I want to add platform iOS but unable to add platform.

I have also tried to update npm with below command but its not working.
command:

> npm update -g

Here is my terminal output below showing the errors I receive, can anyone recommend a solution to resolve this issue?

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.5.1

Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@~4.5.1
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! Darwin 17.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/admin/ionic 2/Selfstuff daily/SelfStuff Daily Design/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install" "cordova-ios@~4.5.1" "--production" "--save-exact"
npm ERR! node v8.9.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/common@4.1.3 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@4.1.3 wants @angular/common@4.1.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@4.1.3 wants @angular/common@4.1.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.1.3 wants @angular/common@4.1.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.7-pre wants @angular/common@^2.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ionic-angular@3.6.1 wants @angular/common@4.1.3

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/admin/ionic 2/Selfstuff daily/SelfStuff Daily Design/npm-debug.log

[ERROR] Exception:
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update all packages to latest version and try again.